# proof that constructs real numbers from rationals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

[image]

I basically have to generate a sequences of rationals between every two reals and show that the limit is always a real. How do I do this?

Comment: No, that's not at all what the question asks.

Comment: okay, could you tell me what it asks then?

Comment: You are supposed to show that, for any real number $r$, there is a sequence of rationals whose limit is $r$.  As a help in finding such a sequence you can use the fact that between any two real numbers there is a rational number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a sketch, but it has enough info for you to flesh out the proof yourself. Notably, I don't tell you how to find $p$.

By the archimedean property of the real numbers, there is a natural number $n$ such that $n(b-a) > 1$, or that $b-a > \frac1n$. Let $p$ denote the smallest integer
such that $\frac pn > a$ but $\frac pn < b$. This is the number you're looking for.

For the second part of your problem: you can then create a sequence of rational numbers that
converge to $b$. Let $q_1$ denote a rational number between $a$ and $b$, $q_2$ denote a
rational number between $\frac{q_1+b}2$ and $b$, $q_3$ denote a rational between $\frac{q_2+b}2$ and $b$, etc. Then you can show that $q_n \to b$.

Comment: what do you mean you don't understand what it is im asking for?

Comment: never mind, I put down a response to your second question

Comment: thanks. I'm bad at showing sequences converge but i will try.

Comment: ok, i didnt get far.. how would YOU think about showing that the sequence converges?

Comment: You want to prove that $\lim |q_n - b| = 0$, right? Well
$q_1$ is between and $b$, so $|q_1 - b| < b-a$. $q_2$ is in between $\frac{q_1+b}2$ and $b$, which is the MIDPOINT of $q_b$ and $b$. Therefore,
$$
|q_2-b| < \frac{|q_1-b|}2 < \frac{b-a}2.
$$
And in general,
$$
|q_n-b| < \frac{|q_{n-1}-b|}2 < \frac{b-a}{2^n}
$$
So $|q_n - b| \to 0$ and $q_n$ converges to $b$. This is one way to do it, but I think dani_s has an easier solution

Comment: i think you're missing some terms there. but it seems like it will have to be an inductive argument.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you have a limited time to edit comments! I can't fix it, but dani_s has a good solution.

Comment: Wow, thank you GDAL, that is really great. Everytime I see a proof like that I understand it really well, but I can never come up with one on my own.

Answer (score 3):

Fix a real number $x$.

Then there exists a rational number $q_n$ with $x < q_n < x + \frac{1}{n}$ for each natural number $n$.

By comparison theorem, the sequence $q_n$ converges to $x$.

We can choose $x$ for arbitrary hence the problem is proved

Comment: @sranthrop I think the problem assumes that fact and simply asks to prove the existance of the sequence

Comment: Youre absolutely right, sry!

Comment: how can a single rational number be a "sequence"

Comment: can someone answer this for me?

Comment: @terribleatmath: They are saying that for each $n\in\mathbb N$ there exists a rational number $q_n$ such that $x<q_n<x+\frac 1 n$. Here, $q_n$ is not some fixed rational number.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that any given real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers. That is, you would start your proof by saying: "Let $x$ be a given real number". Then you have to construct a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of rational numbers such that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = x.
$$
This means that you need to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that $n\geq N \Rightarrow \lvert x_n - x \rvert < \epsilon$.

Now let $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

1. Convince yourself that, because of the denseness, for each $\epsilon_n$ you can find a rational number $x_n$ such that $\lvert x - x_n \rvert < \epsilon_n$. This constructs your sequence, it is hopefully clear that for $n$ large enough, you in fact make $x_n$ as close to $x$ as you want.
2. Then make the conclusion that for any $\epsilon > 0$ you have exactly what you want.

Comment: this doesn't use the denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ though, does it?

Comment: @terribleatmath: Yes, it does. When you choose $x_n$ you are using the denseness.

Answer (score 1):

Given two real numbers $x$ and $y$ pick an integer $n$ large enough that $n(x-y) = nx - ny > 1$ (you're guaranteed that one exists by the Archimedean property). Then it follows that there exists some integer $m$ such that $nx < m < ny$, so $$x < m/n< y.$$

For the second part, now that you've associated a rational number to every two real numbers $x$ and $y$, try to "pinch" $x$ closer and closer to $y$ to create a sequence of rationals that will converge to $y$.